# Crystal report : how to display comma separated value of a single column at page footer

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal report I have three columns **Sr**,**Particular** and **Remark**.

```
SR     Particular     Remark
1      HD             500 GB
2      RAM            2 GB
3      Charger        878668656
```

I want to display Particular column at page footer as below

```
HD, RAM, Charger
```

can anyone tell me how to display all value of **Particular** column as a comma separated in one line or two as summary at page footer ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I would like to display all the values of "Particular" field as a one row separated by comma at page footer

Comment: [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1060114.aspx?Concatenate+field+details+into+single+field) thread might also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula and place it after all columns in details:

```
Shared Stringvar store;

store:=store+Particular+ ", "
```

Now create one more formula `@Display` and place it in `page footer`

```
Shared Stringvar store;
store
```

Comment: didn't get you why it will show duplicate values.. edit your question to show the output

Comment: What do you mean by "place it after all columns in details"?

Comment: @jitendragarg created formula should be at the right most corner of the detail section

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit confusing. When you say detail section, do you mean details of the table? As in where the table is displayed in Rpt file?

Comment: @jitendragarg No Detail section of the design in Crsytal Reports

Comment: Hey, I am not able to figure it out. Can we talk about it on chat?

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109116/crystal-reports-design

Comment: Can you post a question and explain your requirement along with some screenshot...will try to answer if you are unable to understand then we can chat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614030/displaying-multiple-records-in-crystal-report-as-comma-separated-value

Already posted here.

Comment: @jitendragarg just saw the question posted a comment