# Displaying multiple records in Crystal report as comma separated value

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a view that I am using to display some information in Crystal report file. In some cases, view is supposed to return more than 1 record.

By default, in these cases, Crystal report take the last record and display that one. So, if I have two records with id A and B, I will see only the details of B.

I want to have an option where both A and B are displayed separated by comma.

E.g. if EmployeeDepartment in Employee table has two records (CIS, FINANCE) for employee A, then I want to see @EmployeeDepartment return "CIS, FINANCE" instead of just "FINANCE".

I have been trying to find a way to do this. Till now, I have gotten this far:

Base formula

```
Shared Stringvar store;
store:=store+{TBL_MR_Header.MRHD_Customer_Ref_No}+ ", "
```

Display formula

```
Shared Stringvar store;
store
```

When I run the report, base formula returns "B," instead of "A,B". Display formula on the other hand displays nothing.

I am unsure what I am missing here.

Edit:

I have created a query that returns the two value comma separated, in both records. So, both records display "CIS, FINANCE" instead of "CIS" and "FINANCE" respectively. Now, I have simple problem, how do I put this query in crystal report file? Only option I can find is to use that datasource expert tool but that does not allow updating query.

Edit:

I actually decided to go different route there. I tried putting the base formula in header and display formula in detail section, but that didn't work either. Turns out, one of my colleague tried a trick to solve similar problem. He used the C# code to call a T-SQL query, got the value in CSV format, and passed it as a parameter. It requires an extra trip to database, but it made it easier.

Comment: Looks like you have placed the field on wrong section... can you show your design and location where did you place the formula and field

Comment: They are both in same section. I don't need the details, so I have that as suppressed.

Comment: question is in which section you placed base formula and in which section you placed display formula?

Comment: They are both in detail section.

Comment: tha was the main resoin for your issue... change the positions.. place base formula in detail and display formula in footer (Any footer as per your requirement)

Comment: I want the display formula in details section though. :/

Comment: any specific reason to display in detail section? what is your exact requirement?

Comment: I am receiving two records in one case. It is a summary report, where almost every data is same. Only thing different is the actual record number, and I have to list all the record numbers out. Basically something like "we have records (record1, record2, record3...) showing that you still have pending invoices (invoice1, invoice2...)". This is part of the report body. This summary is sent as a reminder to the customers.

Comment: are you resetting the formula? normally if in detail first record will show only one value and next record will show concatination of both values with sapertaed by `,`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. I actually decided to go different route there. I was not resetting the formula, I tried putting the base formula in header and display formula in detail section, but that didn't work either. 

Turns out, one of my colleague tried a trick to solve similar problem. He actually used the C# code to call a T-SQL query, got the value in CSV format, and passed it as a parameter. It requires an extra trip to database, but it made it easier. 

BTW, I still have the question bookmarked. Maybe I can use your formula for doing simple summary in report footers. :)