# How to display comma separated value of a single column at group footer section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-server

I have a table Like bellow:

```
Column1 Column2 Column2 
1        A       B
1        A       V
1        E       F
1        E       D
```

In Crystal Report I need a formula which will return A,E.

No Detail section.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal report : how to display comma separated value of a single column at page footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076609/crystal-report-how-to-display-comma-separated-value-of-a-single-column-at-page)

Comment: What is your exact output

Comment: @Siva: My expected output is A,E

Comment: @SmitaAhinave: I try it. But not working

Comment: Can you show where are you struck